# Flex movie overlapping other HTML

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I have a Flex movie that contains a text input box and an (optional) dropdown. The design requires that this dropdown fall below the lower edge of the movie, overlapping the HTML below it.

I can set wmode to transparent and can get the dropdown to overlap the HTML fine but then the HTML below is unselectable, even when the dropdown is not visible (flex steals the mouse events).

I am looking at changing the size of the div containing my movie when the user selects / unselects it but have run into a bug; If wmode is set to transparent, Flex doesn't give you activate / deactivate events so I can't change the div's size at the correct time.

Am I on the right track with this solution? If so, how can I detect if the user is currently using my Movie.

If I'm barking up the wrong tree, a little pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated :)

Thanks,

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you increase the size of the div only when the dropdown is, well, dropped down? You can use `ExternalInterface` (or simply `navigateToURL("javascript:...")`) to call the relevant javascript function at the appropriate time.

Comment: Hi David,

Great minds think alike etc :) I've just finished trying that myself  and thought I'd see what other people thought; lo and behold - your answer pops up!


Thanks, good to know I'm on the right track,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

If you want html elements to show above your Flash component you add `<param name=”wmode” value=”transparent”>` to your Flash and style your div with absolute positioning.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Adam,

Already tried that - it works but makes the HTML underneath unselectable :(

I need to be able to show the dropdown when the flash movie is selected but allow the HTML to be selectable / interactive when the dropdown is hidden.